# postgres: session timezone of other sessions

Tags: postgresql

Our DB timezone is UTC. I sometimes have users that forget to change their session timezone to UTC and they then get unwanted behavior (e.g. when using `now()`).

Is there a way to

1. Force all sessions to timezone UTC?
2. At least force them once upon connect?
3. Query all sessions, what time zone settings they use? `pg_stat_activity` does not seem to contain that information.

Example why `timestamp` does not solve all my problems:

```
create table a (c timestamp);
reset timezone;
show timezone; -- UTC
insert into a select now();
select * from a; -- 2024-03-13 12:50:14.515
set timezone to 'UTC+9';
show timezone; -- UTC+9
truncate a;
insert into a select now();
select * from a; -- 2024-03-13 03:50:48.376
reset timezone;
show timezone; -- UTC
select * from a; -- 2024-03-13 03:51:22.854
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can do neither of these things. The session time zone is a global variable in the PostgreSQL backend process and not accessible by other database sessions.

You can set the `TimeZone` parameter in `postgresql.conf`, and that will become the default value for all sessions. But there is no way you can keep an interactive user from overriding `TimeZone` with the `SET` command or the `set_config()` function.

I see little point in forcing `TimeZone` to a certain value. Rather, each database session should set the parameter to whatever is appropriate for the client. If you want your timestamps to look the same for every client (you want to be time zone agnostic), use `timestamp without time zone` instead of `timestamp with time zone`, and your problem is solved.

The advice to avoid `timestamp with time zone` in your situation extends to functions. `now()` returns a `timestamp with time zone`, so you should use `localtimestamp` instead, which returns the transaction timestamp as `timestamp without time zone`.

Comment: TY! Unfortunately using `timestamp` does not solve my problem, I have added an example above to illustrate. When users use `now()`, the problem that the session timezone affects what data ends up in the column still persists, even when the column is of type `timestamp`.

Comment: Use `localtimestamp` instead.